# Is there any good IDE's for code browsing and development better than VS Code in LINUX

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ide

I am in a LINUX environment and using VS Code for code browsing which I mostly use for development too. But, the search results are very slow, and sometimes it won't give me results for the definition. Can someone suggest a better IDE for code browsing and development?

I am new to the LINUX environment and very comfortable in using GUI and prefer over default VIM and command-line interface and use of grep.

Comment: For what language?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, I use C and Python programming languages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be moved to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JetBrains IDE's clion and pycharm is good enough for C and Python under Linux.